# WPF Rect Transform

Tags: wpf, matrix, transform, rect

I am trying to apply `RotateTransform` to a `Rect` object with the following code.

```
Rect transformed = this.Rectangle;
transformed.Transform(this.rotateTransform.Value);
DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();
DrawingContext context = visual.RenderOpen();
context.DrawRectangle(null, new Pen(Brushes.Blue, 2), transformed);
context.Close();
canvas.Children.Add(visual);
```

but the rectangle is not rotated. However when I push the transformation to the `DrawingContext`, as in the following code, rectangle is transformed correctly.

```
Rect transformed = this.Rectangle;
DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();
DrawingContext context = visual.RenderOpen();
context.PushTransform(this.rotateTransform);
context.DrawRectangle(null, new Pen(Brushes.Blue, 2), transformed);
context.Pop();
context.Close();
canvas.Children.Add(visual);
```

Is there a way to transform a Rect as in the first code fragment with `Rect.Transform(Matrix)` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prabably because your rotation is not multiple of 90deg. Transform on Rect results in rect that it parallel to x & y axis!

- First case renders modified rectangle that is not rotated a syou desire - seems to be bouding box after rotation
- Second case doest what you wish - it first "rotate content", then draws rectangle

Comment: Yes first case draws a bounding box of the rotated rectangle in the second case. So I guess rotating a Rect as in first case is not possible.